# Одновременный запуск monkeyrunner на разных устройствах

Tags: android, adb

День добрый . Возникла проблема 
Имеем код

```
start monkeyrunner С:\1\1script.py
start monkeyrunner С:\1\2script.py
```

Его запускаю в CMD.Эти скрипты для разных устройств. Первый для первого,второй для второго.В чем собственно проблема,скрипты выполняются последовательно.А одновременно ну не как не хочет. Вроде устройства разные.Не пойму в чем дело.
В диспетчере задач видно что запускается[image: введите сюда описание изображения] два java. Но второй ждет пока не исполниться первый .

Возможно ли ка то запускать одновременно ?